# Can I extract information from linkedIn using java HtmlUnit library?

Tags: java, linkedin-api, htmlunit

I tried hard to find a way to extract data from my LinkedIn account without 
 using the REST API but any result :/ Anyone know if it's possible and how? 
 When I tried this code in Eclipse the result were either a 
 NullPointerException or null when I selected some fields from the response 
 html page.
 Note that the selector path works well in the console of the browser.
 Thank you very much.

```
String url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?goback=&trk=hb_signin";
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage(url); 
final HtmlForm loginForm = loginPage.getFormByName("login");
final HtmlSubmitInput button = loginForm.getInputByName("signin");
final HtmlTextInput usernameTextField = 
loginForm.getInputByName("session_key");
final HtmlPasswordInput passwordTextField = 
loginForm.getInputByName("session_password");
usernameTextField.setValueAttribute("something@outlook.com");
passwordTextField.setValueAttribute("**************");
final HtmlPage response = button.click();
loginPage=webClient.getPage("https://www.linkedin.com/in/issa-hammoud-
0a2802114/");
System.out.println(loginPage.querySelector("#profile-wrapper > div.pv-
content.profile-view-grid.neptune-grid.two-column.ghost-animate-in > 
div.core-rail > section div > div > button > img");
```

Comment: Maybe disabling Javascript is a bad idea here. You can try to disable JS in your real browser and then try to login. I fear this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a secured connection (HTTPS) you need to specify `getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);`

Also make sure you enable cookies `getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);`

Having said that you should really be using the Linkedin's REST API.

Hope that helps